# change bash script so that no user input is required

Tags: bash, shell-script

For development purposes, I use a script that automatically connects to a host to do stuff.
I always need to hit the [ENTER] key so that it connects and reconnects (upon reboot of the host). I would like to modify it so, that no user interaction is required. How can do this?

I don't need lessons on using the `root` account to login, it's all under control - please, just believe me. (embedded platform, no user I/O. Plus `root` account will be disabled before going live) There also is no password assigned to it, either!
What I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$3" == "auto" ] ; then
    arg= 'sleep 1';
    ssharg='-v -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222';
else
    arg= 'read';
    ssharg='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222';
fi
#$dbg should be executed when connecting with parameter lx
dbg=`scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -P 2222 ~/local/script root@$1:/path/to/script`;`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -p 2222 root@$1 -n /path/to/script`;

if [ $2 == "lx" ] ; then
    $dbg;
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222 root@$1; echo "Reconnect?";sleep 1; while $arg; < /dev/tty; do $dbg; ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222 root@$1; echo "Reconnect?"; done

...
More similar elifs checking for other parameters (in $2) without requirement to tun $dbg beforehand
...
```

Which works fine only that I have to press [ENTER] after launching the script and to reconnect.

Comment: Can you give us a clue? Where in the script does it ask you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
    arg= 'read';
```

Because there's a space after `=`, this line temporarily sets the `arg` variable to the empty string, then executes the `read` command which reads data from stdin -- since you don't redirect any data into read's stdin, the user must enter a line of text on the terminal. `read` stores the user's entry into the `$REPLY` variable. Following this, the `arg` variable will be unset.

To assign the `'read'` string to the `arg` variable, you must not put whitespace around `=`

---

This part looks suspect: `while $arg; < /dev/tty; do` -- why is there a semicolon after $arg?

Comment: You might also want to read BashFAQ 50 [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: This link is great! I'll applied your suggestions on top but it still doesn't quite work yet, I'll try around a bit more! Thanks in any case!